# Get userID of current user logged in from server using asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

How to get userID of current user logged in from server using asp.net vb?

Comment: What is the exact question. Whats the end purpose?
In Windows, you can have multiple users logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ASP.NET Membership Provider? Then it would be Profile.UserId.

Did you create your own membership system?

Are you talking about getting the Windows User?
I think you can use:

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]
```

Comment: No. am not using ASP.NET Membership provider........
i want my  loginID from my system..
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

```
    I got the answer.and thanks for helping me...

    Dim strUserId As String
    Dim aryUserId As String()
    strUserId = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
    aryUserId = strUserId.Split("\")
    Response.write(aryUserId(1))
```